# Self defined field? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I'm just getting started on SQL Server and have this little problem
I need a "License" column for my "Clients" table that self defines it's cells as follows:
An **auto incremented number** + "**-**" + the 3 last numbers of "**ID**" + '**f**' if "`gender"='female`' or "**m**" if "`gender"='male`'
Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to check out the dba Stack Exchange site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server

Comment: Never noticed it
Will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use computed column for this purpose

here is how you can do it
added autoid as auto inremented number so it can be used in the computed column.

```
create table Table1
( 
  autoid int IDENTITY(1,1),
  id int,
  gender varchar(5),

  license as cast(autoid as varchar(20))+ '-' +
             cast(id%1000 as varchar(20))+ (case when gender ='female' then 'f' else 'm' end)
  )
```

Comment: Well, now I see why the downvotes
That's fairly simple, I was trying to figure it out using only one column
Is there a way to solve it without adding an autoid column?

Comment: @minusnine, i don't see a way with out autoid, as you want it be incremented all the time, if your ID column is already identity column, then you can use that too

Comment: I got told there's indeed a way to do it without an autoid column, but you need to define a function first, I'll se if I can do it
Plus

cast(id%1000 as varchar(20))

Doesn't always return the last three digits of an ID

RIGHT(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(20)),3)
Does the job better

Anyway, thanks for the help!